# Is there such a thing as a reasonably accurate IBM 486 PC emulator for Windows 10?

Tags: simulation, emulator

Note that I already know about Virtualbox, DOSBox and VMware, and have used them all on and off for 20 years. I find them to be bad. It doesn't feel like I'm using a classic computer when I use those. It feels like it's running the software as fast as it can on my modern machine. It feels... "fake".

I very much realize that an *actual* simulator of a real 486 PC is impossible with today's best hardware, and probably will be for 50+ years into the future, so I'm not expecting a 100% perfect simulation of every single electron in the exact model I grew up with.

Still, it seems like there ought to be something better than the ones I've mentioned, which seem to be not for nostalgia but rather for running/testing legacy stuff for business use. I want essentially a digital version of my first computer, which was an IBM 486 PC, to escape into in full screen and play around with.

Comment: What is to stop you from buying an old 486 computer instead of emulating? You already mentioned the most popular pieces of software did not work out, so anything that is emulated on modern hardware will automatically feel fake. Granted, finding a 486 these days may be somewhat harder but I think still doable.

Comment: DOSbox defaults to Pentium 1 speeds, and can be slowed:
https://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#SpeedHelp
Is there anything more than more slowness, that you are looking for?